# List column value for all databases that have a specific table and column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What I am really looking for is the name of each database with table `ApplicationVersion` and column `[Version]` as well as the value in `[Version]`. Some of my databases don't have the specified table column and should be ignored. The table always has only one row.

```
Database    ApplicationVersion
DB_001      5.123.0.234
DB_002      5.123.0.234
DB_003      6.223.0.435
```

Comment: Databases don't have columns, tables have columns. Is that what you are looking for, and also to check the value of every column in every database for the string "ApplicationVersion"?

Comment: @Nic, Thanks for that! You're right and that is what I am looking for. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really, really, really recommend against `sp_MSforeachdb`. It's easy, sure, but it is undocumented, unsupported, and [buggy as all get out](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

Here is a dynamic SQL solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #x([Database] sysname, ApplicationVersion varchar(32));

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
  BEGIN TRY
    INSERT #x EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(name) +N'.sys.sp_executesql 
    N''SELECT DB_NAME(), MAX(Version) FROM dbo.ApplicationVersion'';
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT CHAR(32);
  END CATCH;'
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE state = 0; -- database is online

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT [Database], ApplicationVersion FROM #x;

DROP TABLE #x;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the garbage that I came up with while Aaron was killing it. Same result with much less style.

```
declare database_cursor cursor 
local static read_only forward_only
for select name from sys.Databases;

create table #ApplicationVersion
(
    DatabaseName varchar(128),
    [Version] varchar(128)
)

declare @DatabaseName varchar(127);

open database_cursor
fetch next from database_cursor into @DatabaseName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
exec (
    'use ' + @DatabaseName +
    'declare @count int;
     set @count = (select count(name) from sys.tables where name = N''ApplicationVersion'')
     if (@count) > 0
     begin
       insert into #ApplicationVersion select ''' + @DatabaseName + ''', [Version] from ApplicationVersion
     end'
    )
    fetch next from database_cursor into @DatabaseName
end
close database_cursor
deallocate database_cursor

select * from #ApplicationVersion
drop table #ApplicationVersion
```

Comment: have a +1 for effort; and good job with the cursor options.

Comment: I'd just be careful with `Sys` vs. `sys` - case can bite you (or future readers).